# Angular - ngRepeat and empty Inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I currently have an ng-repeat with a list of inputs. If the inputs are empty, the LI is hidden.

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel" ng-if="value !== ''">
    <input ng-model="jewel[key]" />
</li>
```

This is great.. however, I allow the user to 'edit' the input if it's visible on the page. The problem, if they remove all the characters from the input, the LI disappears because the value becomes empty.

How can I stop the LI disappearing when the user is simply editing the input box?

Comment: unrelated to your question, why are you doing "jewel[key]" in your ng-model when you can simply use "value"?

Comment: Because im passing $scope.jewel to my API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try one time binding..

```
ng-if="::value"

<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in jewel" ng-if="::value !== ''">
    <input ng-model="jewel[key]" />
</li>
```

Comment: Hmmmm getting this error: Token ':' not a primary expression

Comment: Should have mentioned i had multiple expressions in my ng-if. Fixed it with ng-if="::(key !== 'picture' && value !== ' ')". Thank you

Comment: Welcome Richard Roberts